# npm python-shell not working with electron

Tags: javascript, python, npm, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to link a python script with Electron app using the npm's python-shell package.

The condition is to execute the script whenever I click on a button. So, suppose my directory contains:

```
main.js (electron file)
index.js (my script)
index.html
main.py
```

In index.js, I write the following code to import python-shell and execute the main.py script:

```
function get_input() {
    var python = require("python-shell")
    var path = require("path")

    var options = {
        scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, './python/')
    }

    var weather = new python('main.py', options);

    weather.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    })
}
```

In the index.html, I have created a button tag to run this function on click:

```
<button onclick="get_input()">Go!</button>
```

In the main.py, all I do for now is print "hello". Now when I run, **npm start** I recieve the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is not working? I saw many articles on Electron, they all do the same thing and it works. If there is something that I am missing, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var python = require("python-shell")` 
to
 
`const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");`